# error CS0234: using System.Windows.Threading;

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность

Как подключить [Dispatcher Класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netcore-3.0) в unity. Хочу реализовать такой [Образец Диспетчера](http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/).

Но сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой :

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'
```

Мой класс который написал :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System;
using System.Windows;
public class IDispatcher : Dispatcher
{
    public List<Action> pending = new List<Action>();
    private static Dispatcher instance;
    public void Invoke(Action fn)
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            pending.Add(fn);
        }
    }
    public void InvokePending()
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            foreach (var action in pending)
            {
                action();
            }

            pending.Clear();
        }
    }
    public static Dispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                // Instance singleton on first use.
                instance = new Dispatcher();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Windows.Threading](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading?view=netcore-3.0) - это API для работы с многопоточностью в Windows Presentation Foundation. С Unity3D его никак не скрестить. В статье по вашей ссылке в разделе **Implementation under Unity3d** дан пример реализации класса Dispatcher без WPF, вам нужно сделать то же самое.

Comment: Как я привел в ответе?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Да.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IDispatcher
{
    void Invoke(Action fn);
}
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
...
}
```